# Created an application to learn to add rive splash screen animations in flutter app project

Tags: flutter, dart, splash-screen, flare, rive

I followed the tutorial of adding a splash screen in an app in flutter using rive animation tool, but the splash screen won't show up.

Link which i followed:- https://pub.dev/packages/rive_splash_screen

**Code in main.dart file**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rive_splash_screen/rive_splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:rive/rive.dart';
import 'dart:ui';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: SplashScreen.navigate(
        name: 'assets/doublersplashscreen.riv',
        next: (_) => const MyHomePage(),
        until: () => Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5)),
        startAnimation: 'Splash',
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      height: 400,
      width: 300,
    );
  }
}
```

**Code in pubspec.yaml file**

[Code in pubspec.yaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTbjz.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used your code and a sample rive's community-made animation to reproduce the issue. But I could not, and everything worked as expected. So please check the following steps:

1- Be sure that your animation path is added correctly to `pubspec.yaml`:

`pubspec.yaml`

```
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
 
  assets:
    - assets/
```

2- Be sure that the `riv` file's path is written accurately in the `SplashScreen.navigate` widget. Check if there is an `uppercase` in the provided path.

```
home: SplashScreen.navigate(
  name: 'assets/alarm.riv',
  next: (_) => const MyHomePage(title: 'Demo App'),
  until: () => Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5)),
  startAnimation: 'bell',
),
```

3- Lastly, even if this can not be causing this problem, be sure that you are providing the correct animation name. If you don't, animation will show up but won't animate as expected.

Check the following repository on [Github](https://github.com/BBarisKilic/Stack-OverFlow-Solutions/tree/master/question_72498194).

If you have further problems, please don't hesitate to write in the comments.